# Zero-width characters embedded in phone number whenever they are copied from the macOS address book

Tags: contacts, unicode

Whenever I use Contacts.app to fill out a form on a website, I have a problem with any phone number field.

Contacts.app adds unicode "left-to-right override" (U+202D codepoint: E2 80 AD in UTF-8 contexts, 20 2D in UTF-16 contexts) before the first digit, and "pop directional formatting" (U+202C codepoint: E2 80 AC in UTF-8 contexts, 20 2C in UTF-16 contexts) after the last digit. Many websites get upset by this, because those are not recognised as valid phone number digits. As they are zero-width symbols, the first few times I saw this problem I didn't even understand what was going wrong.

Note that this still happens if I turn off JavaScript or use a desktop text editor like TextWrangler (TextWrangler is how I originally found out which zero-width symbols were being inserted); as it happens, I only care about websites because websites are the only thing which validates that phone numbers match a pattern such as the regex `[0-9()+\s]*`

This happens with all phone numbers in Contacts, regardless of whose (some are formatted as UK, some as USA, some as German).

Method: open Contacts.app, select any person, double (or triple) click on a phone number to select all of it, ⌘C-⌘V to copy-paste; if I paste into an app which shows non-printable characters like TextWrangler then I can see their existence, if I paste into a web browser it's present but zero-width, as arrow keys 'stick' at those positions and the delete key does in fact remove them.

It happens as described in both Safari and Chrome. In Firefox, it behaved slightly differently, and seemed to automatically delete the extra characters as soon as I pass through them with my arrow keys (?!).

How do I stop Contacts.app from adding these unicode symbols?

Comment: can we have a screen shot, you know picture speaks 1000 words

Comment: also which browser are you using

Comment: @Buscar웃 screens it's won't show zero width characters and so I can't see how that would help

Comment: @Mark you can show them https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/replace-zero-width-charac/lgaiigbekmcejmhenhhleeaicbcjjddi

Comment: Please explain to us the process you are using. Is it just your number or all the numbers from Contacts.

Comment: @Buscar All phone numbers in Contacts, regardless of whose (some are formatted as UK, some as USA, some as German); Method: open Contacts.app, select any person, double (or triple) click on a phone number to select all of it, ⌘C-⌘V to copy-paste; if I paste into an app which shows non-printable characters like TextWrangler then I can see their existence, if I paste into a web browser it's *present* but *zero-width*, as arrow keys 'stick' at those positions and the delete key does in fact remove them — but it would be much better if they were never present in the first place.

Comment: Browser: happens as described in both Safari and Chrome. In Firefox, it behaved slightly differently, and seemed to automatically delete the extra characters as soon as I pass through them with my arrow keys (?!), but hex-dumping it showed that two different zero-width characters were present: 20 2D and 20 2C, which are the same unicode symbols but as UTF-16 instead of as UTF-8. TextWrangler showed the hexdump I originally wrote (I didn't find a browser-based hex-dump until just now), but this new hex dump is the same for all browsers. Even then, the unicode character is the same.

Comment: so far it looks like they do not come from Contacts.app they are added by the website you are visiting and filling out they forms.

Comment: just for fun try this https://www.umpox.com/zero-width-detection/

Comment: I too am having this problem. I did not have it with my US number, but when I moved and got a Swedish number, Apple Contacts did this. I have tried everything to remove it. Deleting my card, recreating it. Deleting the number and re-adding it by typing. I cannot get rid of these invisible characters in my phone number in Apple Contacts.

Comment: Was anyone able to solve this problem? It is VERY annoying to me as I copy from Contacts.app quite often. In many cases, it didn't matter, but recently on several websites, it won't allow me to submit the form because of those two invisible characters.

Comment: @VicJang if anyone solved it they never told me the solution, as it still affects me.

Comment: It's been two years and the problem is still there...

Comment: Have you reported it as a bug to Apple?  If not, please do so, and repeat (or link to) this post.

Comment: I suspect part of the problem is what happened with e-mail addresses.  A long time ago, someone wrote a book on Javascript that contained code to validate e-mail addresses.  But he ignored the RFC that defined the syntax and his code did not allow '+'.  hundreds of web teams copied his code and refused to accept valid addresses like `usedID+modifier@domain.tld` which I and many other people used to sort mail (and figure out who was feeding addresses to spammers).

Answer (score 9):

***update Dec 2023:*** This is still NOT fixed as of macOS 14.1.2 Sonoma / Contacts.app Version 14.0 (2565).

Adding another reason why this is isn't simply a cosmetic problem. Recently I was adding an address on Amazon and got blocked. It kept telling me *"remove invalid characters from phone number field"*. I'd forgotten about this old bug and wasted a lot of time checking, re-pasting and trying to format the number in various ways. Finally I remembered—Apple does not care about Contacts.app!

[image: amazon-doesnt-like-it]

---

I've filed bugs #47763641 & #5235503 with Apple, and I encourage others to report it. Hopefully one day it will receive some attention. With each new macOS release, I lose more faith that they will— it's already survived 5 major OS releases and dozens of minor point updates.

#### Repro steps

1. From Contacts.app, right-click → Copy on a phone number.
2. Paste into Sublime Text or any other plaintext editor.
3. Save as `test.txt`
4. Open in a Hex Editor, I used [Hex Fiend](https://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) in this example
5. You can now see the extra bytes (I highlighted them below)

[image: zwsp-chars-screenshot]

A couple of bits of information:

1. This seems to only affect phone# fields. Others such as email, addresses, notes etc don't exhibit this bug.
2. If, instead of using <kbd>⌘command + A</kbd> (select-all), you very carefully select just from the start of the phone# to the end and then copy, the unwanted zwsp characters aren't copied.

#### My workarounds for now

1. I've removed Contacts.app from my Dock and replaced it with [Cardhop](https://flexibits.com/cardhop), which correctly copies phone numbers.
2. An Alfred workflow [luckman212/alfred-copy-workaround](https://github.com/luckman212/alfred-copy-workaround) that I mapped to <kbd>⌘⇧C</kbd> that copies the selected field and trims the whitespace. Not exactly elegant, but it works well enough until Apple fixes this.

Comment: The time is August 2022. I'm using an Apple M1 MacBook Pro with macOS Monterey 12.5 and this freaking problem still exists. Are they not aware of the issue or what..

Comment: I filed a new bug report. Hopefully it makes a difference.

Comment: @VicJang The time is September 2023. Another year, another major OS update goes by without a fix for this.

Comment: "An Alfred workflow that I mapped to ⌘⇧C that copies the selected field and trims the whitespace. Not exactly elegant, but it works well enough until Apple fixes this."
I have Alfred but never used workflows.  Can you explain how to add this one?

Comment: @JohnSpringer I uploaded the workflow to GitHub and updated my answer to point to the repo. Workflows are basically the only reason to use Alfred, so you should really explore them!

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a confirmation (to rebut the answer that says that Contacts is not doing it).

Here is the result of pasting Apple's support number that I typed into Contacts and then copy/pasted into od -bc:

```
% od -bc
‭(800) 275-2273‬0000000   342 200 255 050 070 060 060 051 040 062 067 065 055 062 062 067
         342 200 255   (   8   0   0   )       2   7   5   -   2   2   7
0000020   063 342 200 254                                                
           3 342 200 254                                                
0000024
```

I contacted Apple with a support request, escalated the request to the second level and successfully got the support person to verify that this is still happening (on 13.1) on his own computer.

I've written up detailed steps to reproduce and sent them through as a bug report attached to my case. We'll see what happens.

But you're not crazy - Contacts DOES insert extraneous characters before and after phone numbers copy/pasted.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for confirming this behaviour. I've just had a Mac user complaining that outbound calls from their MS Teams app were failing due to malformed dialstrings.

As you can't make macOS or Contacts use a specific app to place calls, they were cutting and pasting the number from Contacts into the dialpad in Teams. The dial string normalisation regex to transform UK mobile numbers (with an 07 prefix) into e164 was failing because of the hidden characters.

**edit**

It turns out you *can* change the default calling app in macOS, the setting’s just in a non-obvious place (ie. the Contacts app or System Settings). Open FaceTime and go to Settings in the menu. From there you can set MS Teams as your default app for calls