# How to copy phone number from Mac Contacts app without extra symbols?

Tags: macos, contacts, contacts.app

Often I need to copy a phone number form Contacts app on mac and paste it in some web form etc.

This is what gets copied: `‭+1 (111) 111-11-11‬`

Perfectly I'd like it to be just numbers without spaces, dashes and brackets, but the most annoying is an empty character at the end, because you can't see it and the form doesn't accept the phone number. Why is this empty character there?

I tried to edit phone number, and I can remove it from the end of phone number, but it not gets saved.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I don't have an answer and it's extremely annoying.

Comment: Very similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/337101/100302